# Firebase data is not getting displayed and getting error

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

When I searched anything it did nothing but when I press button my app get crash and getting error. I don't know know what is wrong.

**Main Activity**

```
public class CriminalRecords extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "CriminalRecords";


    private EditText msearchfield;
    private ImageButton msearchbtn;
    private FloatingActionButton mFab;

    private RecyclerView mResultList;

    private DatabaseReference mCriminalDatabase;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_criminal_records, container, false);

        msearchfield=view.findViewById(R.id.SearchCriminal);
        msearchbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
        mFab = view.findViewById(R.id.AddCriminals);
        mResultList = view.findViewById(R.id.Criminal_result_list);
        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mCriminalDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Criminals");

        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(), Add_Criminals.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        msearchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String searchText = msearchfield.getText().toString();
                firebaseSearch(searchText);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void firebaseSearch(String searchText) {
        Query firebaseSearchQuery = mCriminalDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseSearch: searching");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Criminalupload>options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Criminalupload>()
                .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,Criminalupload.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Criminalupload, CriminalViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Criminalupload, CriminalViewHolder>(options)
        {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CriminalViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Criminalupload model) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: BindView Active");
                holder.setDetails(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getName(),model.getImageid(),model.getAddress1(),model.getAddress2(),model.getAddress3(),model.getMobnum());
                Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Bindview done");
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CriminalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseSearch: setting adapter");
        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseSearch: addapter set");

    }

    //View Holder Class
    public static class CriminalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;
        public CriminalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDetails(Context ctx,String CName, String Cimg, String Addres1, String Addres2, String Addres3, Long Mob){
            Log.d(TAG, "setDetails: setting details");
            TextView cname = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.cProfileName);
            TextView caddress1 = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.CriminalAddress);
            TextView caddress2 = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.CriminalAddress2);
            TextView caddress3 = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.CriminalAddress3);
            TextView cmobile = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.CriminalMobile);
            CircleImageView cprof = (CircleImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.cProfileImg);

            cname.setText(CName);
            caddress1.setText(Addres1);
            caddress2.setText(Addres2);
            caddress3.setText(Addres3);
            cmobile.setText(Math.toIntExact(Mob));
            Glide.with(ctx).load(Cimg).into(cprof);

        }

    }

}
```

**Error**

> 2020-02-22 19:57:17.804 15653-15653/com.example.crimerecords D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   2020-02-22 19:57:17.805 15653-15653/com.example.crimerecords E/AndroidRuntime:
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.crimerecords, PID: 15653
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7079)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1897)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:414)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>
> 2020-02-22 19:57:17.820 15653-15653/com.example.crimerecords I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15653 SIG: 9

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onCreateViewHolder` method returns `null`, while it should return a new view holder for the data from the database.

A typical implementation would look something like this:

```
public CriminalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.criminal, parent, false);

    return new CriminalViewHolder(view);
}
```

Where `R.layout.criminal` is the layout that you want to use to show a node from the database.

This is all quite well covered in the FirebaseUI documentation on [using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme.md/), so I recommend spending some time reading that.